# Support for Tensorflow 2.0 in Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, object-detection-api

I am using TF Object Detection API for training a model that I will eventually deploy using tf-serving. I plan to take the output of this network (at intermediate CNN layers) and build additional networks for other functionality besides object detection. I plan to develop new networks in TF 2.0. However, for this to work smoothly, (I suspect) that Object Detection API will need to be updated to support TF-2.0.

**Is there  a plan to update the TF OD API to TF 2.0?**

I tried running the model_builder_test and it failed as shown below, because tensorflow 2.0 doesn't support contrib anymore.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 23, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 19, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import box_predictor_builder
  File "/models/research/object_detection/builders/box_predictor_builder.py", line 18, in <module>
    from object_detection.core import box_predictor
  File "/research/object_detection/core/box_predictor.py", line 35, in <module>
    slim = tf.contrib.slim
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow 2.0 is still in Alpha. Fortunately, support for Tensorflow 2.0 will eventually be added. See this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/6423)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a plan to migrate the Object Detection API to TF2.0, but it will take months. In the meantime please use TF1.x for the API.

Comment: Following the official release of TF 2.0 this month, I was wondering if anyone is aware of any updates on the migration of Object Detection API to TF2.0?